# branch.io link redirected non-stop when app isn't installed

Tags: ios, branch.io

I am trying to implement branch.io deep link in my iOS app and when I test it and my app isn't installed yet, it keeps redirecting me to my fallback URL as you can see in [this animated gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/2ysWltaaE97uKgWeqt).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Branch link opens an iOS app via two mechanisms:

- URI Schemes
- Universal Links

To ensure that the link opens your iOS app, please check the following:

- Link Settings on the Branch dashboard
- Info.plist file of your app (needed for URI Schemes)
- Entitlements file of your app (needed for Universal Links)

Under your [Link Settings](https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings), please confirm that you have:

- Checked 'I have an iOS App'
- Entered an iOS URI Scheme
- Checked 'Enable Universal Links'
- Entered the Team ID and Bundle ID from your Apple Developer Account

Under your app configuration in your Xcode project, please confirm that you have:

- Entered the same URI Scheme in the [Info.plist file](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#configure-infoplist)
- Entered the 'applinks:' in the [Associated Domains](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#configure-associated-domains)
- Added the [Entitlements file](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#configure-entitlements) to the correct build target

As a sanity check, feel free to use our [Universal Link Validator](https://docs.branch.io/pages/resources/validation-tools/#universal-link-validator).

At this point, a basic Quick Link on the dashboard should launch your app from the native Notes app. Oftentimes, the configuration is correct, but a Branch link could have special redirects or control parameters that prevent it from opening the app. To verify that this is the issue, append `?debug=true` at the end your test link (e.g. `https://branch.app.link/abcd123?debug=1`) and enter it on your desktop. Under Link Data, ensure that `has_app` and `$always_deeplink` are not set to `false`.

Lastly, if the Branch link still does not open the app, it might be that you are clicking the Branch link from an app or browser that does not support Universal Links. Please take a look at the limitations here:

- [iOS Universal Links: Advanced](https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/universal-links/#advanced)
- [iOS Universal Links: Common issues that cause universal links to fail](https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/universal-links/#common-issues-that-cause-universal-links-to-fail)

If all else fails, feel free to submit a ticket to **support@branch.io** and include your Branch link, screenshots of Entitlements and Info.plist files, and test plan in the description. This information will help us reach a quicker resolution.